# Can I convert an `IterableDataset` to ` Dataset`?

Tags: huggingface-datasets

I want to load a large dataset, apply some transformations to some fields, sample a small section from the results and store as files so I can later on just load from there.

Basically something like this:

```
ds = datasets.load_dataset("XYZ", name="ABC", split="train", streaming=True)
ds = ds.map(_transform_record)
ds.shuffle()[:N].save_to_disk(...)
```

`IterableDataset` doesn't have a `save_to_disk()` method. Makes sense as it's backed by an iterator, but then I'd expect some way to convert an iterable to a regular dataset (by iterating over it all and store in memory/disk, nothing too fancy).

I tried to use `Dataset.from_generator()` and use the `IterableDataset` as the generator (`iter(ds)`), but it doesn't work as it's trying to serialize the generator object.

Is there an easy way, like `to_iterable_dataset()` just vice-versa?

Comment: sadly I haven't... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must cache an `IterableDataset` to disk to load it as a `Dataset`. One way to do this is with `Dataset.from_generator`:

```py
from functools import partial
from datasets import Dataset

def gen_from_iterable_dataset(iterable_ds):
    yield from iterable_ds

ds = Dataset.from_generator(partial(gen_from_iterable_dataset, iterable_ds), features=iterable_ds.features)
```

- [source](https://github.com/huggingface/datasets/issues/6012)

Comment: That works, thanks! The only change in my pseudo-code is that the slice operator "[..]" isn't implemented on an IterableDataset, but `take()`can be used instead.